# jpa eclipse link 2.1 , extracting some properties from complete entity

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to extract only some properties from the complete  DD bean , but while i am trying to run it is showing "Internal problem encountered while compiling" also "Null pointer exception" , please help below is my code.

```
String query = "SELECT NEW PageBean(d.sno,d.format,d.model,d.vendorName,d.resolutionHeight,d.resolutionWidth,d.smartPhone,d.tablet) FROM DD d ";
        TypedQuery<PageBean> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query, PageBean.class);
        List<PageBean> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full error log, meanwhile try creating new object by using package notation.

```
SELECT NEW com.xx.yy.PageBean
```